# Intellij macro not behaving correctly

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I created a macro in Intellij that is trying to navigate individual files for ToolWindows by very simply moving up and down. Mapping up and down to another key only seems to work in the editor (even tho using up arrow works in ToolWindow).

I created a macro by recording an "Up" event on the Project ToolWindow. The macro works correctly when I do "Play Saved Macros". It will move up and highlight the row. However, If I bind it to a Keymapping, it will work but not highlight the row.

e.g. I created a mapping Alt+J mapped as 'Up', and it moves up one file but doesn't highlight the row.

Any ideas as to how to make it highlight, or to actually create a shortcut to do as described?

EDIT: I noticed that when in Structure Tool Window, if I type a letter to start doing a search then run the macro, it will all of a sudden start to work. Maybe I can incorporate that into the macro.

Comment: When you press a an Alt key it seems that it conflicts with the Up navigate action. These actions are not customizable unfortunately, please vote for related issue: [IDEA-108609](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108609). Try this plugins: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9852-ijkl-shortctus